# Equation of a hyperplane in n- dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I know that the equation of a hyperplane in n-dimensions is given by:
$$w^Tx+w_0=0$$
Where $w$ is a vector that is perpendicular to the surface of the hyperplane and $w_0$ is a constant.
I also know that if $w_0=0$, then the plane passes through the origin.
My question is, what is the physical significance of the constant term $w_0$. Is it the distance of the plane to the origin? If not then what is its physical significance?

Comment: If $w$ has unit length, then yes, $w_0$ is the (signed) distance from the origin to the hyperplane.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the length of $w$ is $1$.

Since $w$ is perpendicular to the hyperplane, the orthogonal projection of the origin to the hyperplane is $\lambda w$ for a unique real number $\lambda$.
The length of $\lambda w$ is $|\lambda|$, this is the distance of the origin to the hyperplane, and since $\lambda w$ is assumed to be on the hyperplane, it satisfies
$$w^T(\lambda w)+w_0=0\implies \lambda=-w_0$$
since $w^Tw=\|w\|^2=1$ by assumption.